# VBS Date Formatting

Tags: date, vbscript, formatting, format

I have a 2 line code but the date comes out as the following

```
15/January/2022
```

but I need it as either

```
15.01.2022
15012022
```

Is there a way of doing that?

```
FirstDay=DateSerial(Year(Date),(Month(Date)- 1),1)
LastDay=DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date),0)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. But i need two liners for two different sap paths. So first one first date of the previous month and the second last day of the previous month. Basically 01.01.2022 and 31.01.2022

Comment: Sorry I tried but it didnt work :S

Comment: Waiting a help guys. I need a two seperated code that provide me first day and second day of previous month in the format dd.mm.yyyy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry was rushing the values in [`DateAdd()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/cb7z8yf9(v=vs.84)) were wrong way around.

Comment: The day part needs to use `DateAdd()` to increase the date by 1 month then subtract 1 day, this will give you the last day of the month. I’m not building it for you, you have the resources there to have a go yourself.

Comment: Thanks, sure i am on it to create. Basically i am rookie. I have 2 questions regarding the string you wrote. What does “00” and “2” stands for Month? FirstDay = "01." & Right("00" & Month(Date()), 2) & "." & Year(Date())

Comment: The [`Right()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/eh8fefz1(v=vs.84)) takes two characters from the end of a string so by prefixing the date part with `"00"` we can guarantee that any single digit values for day or month are padded with a `0`, so the first day of the month becomes `01` not `1`. That is explained in the duplicate target that’s been flagged.

Comment: Here's the one liner you need - `lastday = Right("00" & Day(DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)))), 2) & "." & Right("00" & Month(Date()), 2) & "." & Year(Date())`. Tested it and it's works.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was so helpful. I added one extra thing which is Month(Date())-1 since I need previous month's last date.